# .net core worker service and query fromSql

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, service, worker

I want to create windows service through worker service in .netcore 3.0

The Goal:

Each 10 minutes, it need to be triggered my worker, and then open the connection to sql server, go to particular db, and table (Car table), and check if there any new records based on before iterration of a service. If there new rows, make an HttpClient call to external api. If not, than do nothing.

So I have Program.cs where I added for my HostBuilder connection string and `opstionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection)`

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var connection = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
                    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CarContext>();
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);//,
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

so, my question is how to consume connection through my database in the class Worker?

Worker class:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                
                //go to db and check if there are new records in last 10 minutes form previous check
                //select count(*) from dbo.Car
                
                //if there new rows, make an api call to 3rd party library - HttpClient

                //wait 10 minutes then repeat
                await Task.Delay(10*60*1000, stoppingToken);


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to inject an IConfiguration instance into Worker so you can access the Connection String and build a DbContext instance in a `using` block for each iteration.

You don't want a single DbContext for your long-running background job.  Instead create a new one each time through the loop.  eg

```
while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
     using (var db = new MyDbContext(myConnectionString))
     {
      //go to db and check if there are new records in last 10 minutes form previous check
      //select count(*) from dbo.Car
    
      //if there new rows, make an api call to 3rd party library - HttpClient


     }

    //wait 10 minutes then repeat
    await Task.Delay(10*60*1000, stoppingToken);
}
```

Comment: so I need to inject through my constructor ICOnfiguration, and then OnStart method for worker to open connection, and OnClose, to close connection, but using statement using just that, mayube I donmt need it. Can you please share an example in order to accept your answer. thanks!